# CSS Scroller Stopped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have a simple image scroller on our homepage. It suddenly stopped working. I did not write the code but while hunting down the problem I noticed the HTML links to an old version of javascript, jquery-1.3.2.min.js.

Hoping the old javascript was the problem, I downloaded jquery-3.1.0.min.js and placed this file into a folder named js on our website. I updated the src= link to the file on our website but it did not fix the problem.

Here is the code:

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(function() {

  //remove js-disabled class
  $("#viewer").removeClass("js-disabled");

  //create new container for images
  $("<div>").attr("id", "container").css({
    position: "absolute"
  }).width($(".wrapper").length * 170).height(170).appendTo("div#viewer");

  //add images to container
  $(".wrapper").each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo("div#container");
  });

  //work out duration of anim based on number of images (1 second for each image)
  var duration = $(".wrapper").length * 3000;

  //store speed for later (distance / time)
  var speed = (parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width())) / duration;

  //set direction
  var direction = "rtl";

  //set initial position and class based on direction
  (direction == "rtl") ? $("div#container").css("left", $("div#viewer").width()).addClass("rtl"): $("div#container").css("left", 0 - $("div#container").width()).addClass("ltr");

  //animator function
  var animator = function(el, time, dir) {

    //which direction to scroll
    if (dir == "rtl") {

      //add direction class
      el.removeClass("ltr").addClass("rtl");

      //animate the el
      el.animate({
        left: "-" + el.width() + "px"
      }, time, "linear", function() {

        //reset container position
        $(this).css({
          left: $("div#imageScroller").width(),
          right: ""
        });

        //restart animation
        animator($(this), duration, "rtl");

        //hide controls if visible
        ($("div#controls").length > 0) ? $("div#controls").slideUp("slow").remove(): null;

      });
    } else {

      //add direction class
      el.removeClass("rtl").addClass("ltr");

      //animate the el
      el.animate({
        left: $("div#viewer").width() + "px"
      }, time, "linear", function() {

        //reset container position
        $(this).css({
          left: 0 - $("div#container").width()
        });

        //restart animation
        animator($(this), duration, "ltr");

        //hide controls if visible
        ($("div#controls").length > 0) ? $("div#controls").slideUp("slow").remove(): null;
      });
    }
  }

  //start anim
  animator($("div#container"), duration, direction);

  //pause on mouseover
  $("a.wrapper").live("mouseover", function() {

    //stop anim
    $("div#container").stop(true);

    //show controls
    ($("div#controls").length == 0) ? $("<div>").attr("id", "controls").appendTo("div#outerContainer").css({
      opacity: 0.7
    }).slideDown("slow"): null;
    ($("a#rtl").length == 0) ? $("<a>").attr({
      id: "rtl",
      href: "#",
      title: "rtl"
    }).appendTo("#controls"): null;
    ($("a#ltr").length == 0) ? $("<a>").attr({
      id: "ltr",
      href: "#",
      title: "ltr"
    }).appendTo("#controls"): null;

    //variable to hold trigger element
    var title = $(this).attr("title");

    //add p if doesn't exist, update it if it does
    ($("p#title").length == 0) ? $("<p>").attr("id", "title").text(title).appendTo("div#controls"): $("p#title").text(title);
  });

  //restart on mouseout
  $("a.wrapper").live("mouseout", function(e) {

    //hide controls if not hovering on them
    (e.relatedTarget == null) ? null: (e.relatedTarget.id != "controls") ? $("div#controls").slideUp("slow").remove() : null;

    //work out total travel distance
    var totalDistance = parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width());

    //work out distance left to travel
    var distanceLeft = ($("div#container").hasClass("ltr")) ? totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left")) + parseInt($("div#container").width())) : totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#viewer").width()) - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left"))));

    //new duration is distance left / speed)
    var newDuration = distanceLeft / speed;


    //restart anim
    animator($("div#container"), newDuration, $("div#container").attr("class"));

  });

  //handler for ltr button
  $("#ltr").live("click", function() {

    //stop anim
    $("div#container").stop(true);

    //swap class names
    $("div#container").removeClass("rtl").addClass("ltr");

    //work out total travel distance
    var totalDistance = parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width());

    //work out remaining distance
    var distanceLeft = totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left")) + parseInt($("div#container").width()));

    //new duration is distance left / speed)
    var newDuration = distanceLeft / speed;

    //restart anim
    animator($("div#container"), newDuration, "ltr");
  });

  //handler for rtl button
  $("#rtl").live("click", function() {

    //stop anim
    $("div#container").stop(true);

    //swap class names
    $("div#container").removeClass("ltr").addClass("rtl");

    //work out total travel distance
    var totalDistance = parseInt($("div#container").width()) + parseInt($("div#viewer").width());

    //work out remaining distance
    var distanceLeft = totalDistance - (parseInt($("div#viewer").width()) - (parseInt($("div#container").css("left"))));

    //new duration is distance left / speed)
    var newDuration = distanceLeft / speed;

    //restart anim
    animator($("div#container"), newDuration, "rtl");
  });
});
```

```css
/* js-disabled class - set image sizes so they all fit in the viewer */

.js-disabled img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  /* 9-16-16: Changed margin from 30 to 0*/
  margin: 30px 0 0;
}
#outerContainer {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  clear: both;
}
#outerContainer h2 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
}
#imageScroller {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
}
#viewer {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
#imageScroller a:active,
#imageScroller a:visited {} #imageScroller a img {
  border: 0;
}
#controls {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 47px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  z-index: 10;
}
#controls a {
  width: 37px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
}
#controls a:active,
#controls a:visited {} #title {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.imgSpacer {
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#outerContainer h4 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div id="outerContainer">
    <h2>Many of the fine organizations who use AccuZIP products</h2>
    <div id="imageScroller">
      <div id="viewer" class="js-disabled">
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_aaa.gif" alt="AAA" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_accutrend.gif" alt="AccuTrend" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_aflac.gif" alt="AFLAC" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_alliancetitle.jpg" alt="Alliance Title" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_allstate.jpg" alt="Allstate" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_alphagraphics.jpg" alt="AlphaGraphics" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_americancancersociety.gif" alt="American Cancer Society" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
            <img src="images/customerlogos/75_pipprinting.jpg" alt="PIP Printing" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa2" />
          </a>
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_att.jpg" alt="ATT" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_bestwestern.jpg" alt="Best Western" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_century21.jpg" alt="Century 21" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_chicagotitle.jpg" alt="Chicago TItle" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_chiquita.gif" alt="Chiquita" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_cincinnati_reds.gif" alt="Cincinnati Reds" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_citibank.gif" alt="Citibank" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_coldwellbanker.jpg" alt="Coldwell Banker" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_dg.jpg" alt="Dolce Gabbana" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_dominos.jpg" alt="Dominos" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_dowjones.jpg" alt="Dow Jones" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_fidelity.jpg" alt="Fidelity National Title" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_firstamericantitle.gif" alt="First American Title" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_ikon.jpg" alt="IKON" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_instyprints.jpg" alt="Insty-Prints" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_kwikkopy.jpg" alt="Kwik Kopy" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_letterstream.gif" alt="LetterStream, Inc" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_lucent.jpg" alt="Lucent Technologies" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_mailboxesetc.jpg" alt="Mail Boxes Etc" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_MC_stack_4c.jpg" alt="Mayo Clinic" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_minutemanpress.jpg" alt="Minuteman Press" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_nra.jpg" alt="NRA" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_nyt.jpg" alt="New York Times" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_oldrepublic.jpg" alt="Old Republic" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_postcardmania.gif" alt="PostcardMania" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_prada.jpg" alt="Prada" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_proctorgamble.gif" alt="Proctor and Gamble" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_remax.jpg" alt="REMAX" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_salvationarmy.jpg" alt="Salvation Army" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_shutterfly.jpg" alt="Shutterfly" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_sirSpeedy.jpg" alt="Sir Speedy" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_terribles.jpg" alt="Terribles Hotel" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_uofarizona.jpg" alt="U of Arizona" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_uofiowa.jpg" alt="University of Iowa" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_uofmemphis.jpg" alt="University of Memphis" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_uofmontana.jpg" alt="University of Montana" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_uofpreschurch.jpg" alt="UP" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_uoftennessee.jpg" alt="University of Tennessee" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_upsstore.jpg" alt="UPS Store" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_usc.jpg" alt="USC" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_ustreasury.jpg" alt="US Treasury" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_uw_health.jpg" alt="UW Health" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_venetian.gif" alt="Venetian" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_weightwatchers.gif" alt="Weight Watchers" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_wellsfargo.jpg" alt="Wells Fargo" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_xerox.jpg" alt="Xerox" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
        <a class="wrapper" href="customers/index.htm">
          <img src="images/customerlogos/75_yellowpages.jpg" alt="Yellow Pages" name="aaa" class="imgSpacer" id="aaa">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/customerScroller.js"></script>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>


</body>
```

Comment: did you do any basic debugging, like checking your browser's console for errors?

Comment: Fiddle link should be http://jsfiddle.net/Kfininen/y3aq0qsr/

Comment: You're fiddle is far too much code, and it's unclear what I'm suppose to be looking for. Can you reduce it to only the code needed to demonstrate and replicate the problem? Also, it's unclear how it broke. you said "It suddenly stopped working". What is the expected behavior and what is happening? I know this might be a lot for someone with little coding experience, but it's very difficult to answer the question as it is right now.

Comment: Fiddle aside, you need to put a [mcve] **in your question**. Don't try and game the system by highlighting text as code.

Comment: OK - Most of the HTML code was a ton of <a> tags to all our customer logos. I removed most of them. This is supposed to be a scroller that smoothly scrolls about 175 images in single file right to left. There are no transition effects or anything fancy. "Stopped working" means It no longer scrolls. Now, only some of the images appear. It looks like only the first few that fit across the width of the page are visible in a static bar - no scrolling. Please let me know if I can provide more information or clarify my question further.

Comment: I tried to simplify the link to jsfiddle but the window kept giving me an error and said I have to place it in the brackets. jsfiddle.net/Kfininen/y3aq0qsr

Comment: @K.Fininen This seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/y3aq0qsr/4/  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got your `<script>` tag path incorrect. I replaced it with a CDN and it works.

A the bottom of the `<body>` tag,

**Replace:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

**With:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3aq0qsr/4/)

**Update:**

There is not really a compelling reason why jquery-1.3.2 would not continue to work, so if the application broke there is most likely something else going on. The fact that the Fiddle example was working is a clue... Find what the difference is.

Comment: This resulted in only one logo being displayed and still no scrolling. BUT, i changed the code in the fiddle and it almost looks like it does the same thing. The ATT logo displays as a static image, but it looks like the others are scrolling as they should. Unfortunately, this is not the behavior in the actual page when I go to view it in a browser. The rendered page in the browser only shows the ATT logo and there is no scrolling.

Comment: Give it a couple seconds, then the scrolling starts. I didn't delve into the particulars of the code. You might be missing other references in your file structure.

Comment: Shouldn't we be able to download the current javascript file, jquery-3.1.0.min.js, place it on our website and use that as the source? I tried this and get the same problem as when using the code change mhatch suggested.

Comment: Ok - we looked in the code and found some errors. After fixing that it works EXCEPT in IE. Any suggestions for this one?

Comment: What were the errors? IE version may not support jquery 3x try 2x

Comment: jquery 2x `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Using jquery 2x resulted in disabling the scroller entirely
 in all browsers.

Comment: @K.Fininen Check the devtools console for errors. If there are any JS errors the whole thing will break. You can also look up the plugin you are using to see which versions of jquery it supports.

Comment: Check the contents of this file: `src="js/customerScroller.js"`

Comment: The current code, <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>, only works in Chrome. In Firefox only the ATT logo displays and does not scroll. In IE only enough logos to fill the page width are displayed and no scrolling. So we're pretty much back to square one.

Comment: What is different between your application and the Fiddle above? Your answer will lie there.

Comment: Come to think of it... did you include the contents of `src="js/customerScroller.js"` in the Fiddle example? Also, I cannot help you debug if you delete the example. o-o

Comment: Your help has been appreciated. Unfortunately, I am not knowledgeable enough to understand what you mean by "check the devtools console" (what's that?) or review the .js file (have no clue). We decided to go with a third party app to create a scroller. We were hoping this would be an easy fix and be able to simply swap out the src to the current version of jquery. It's obviously much more complicated than we are prepared to deal with. I will continue to learn and hopefully be able to answer questions someday.